# Free library for chat in android?

Tags: android, sockets, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I want to implement a chat module in my existing app. I have found a way of doing it with GCM & socket programming But i want implement using a plugin or library. Is there any Free library available for android ?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link for chat api.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android

Comment: check telegram api.
https://telegram.org/

Comment: Ok..Suggest me more ..